Two different annotations in cronjob/pod
I have values.yaml cronjob.yaml files
values.yaml
annotiations1:
 vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret:'value1'
 vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status:'value2'
annotiations2:
 vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret:'value3'
 vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status:'value4' 

cronjob.yaml
annotiations:
 dev: |
   {{- with .Values.annotiations1 }}
     {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
   {{- end }}
 uat: |
   {{- with .Values.annotiations2 }}
     {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
   {{- end }}

I had to split it to dev and uat because I have connection with two different dbs.
As I understand I cannot have it without splitting because variables name are the same in
annotiations1 and in annotiations2.
After deploy and helm upgrade in kubectl describe pod I see in Annotations section something like that
Annotations:   dev:
               uat:
               vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret:'value3'
               vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status:'value4'

without values from annotiations1 (dev), is it possible to have two different annotations with the same parameters name ? that's why dev section is empty ?
Want to have in kubectl pod in annotations section two different configuration for dbs with the same parameters name.

Use helm to set a single value based on values
annotiations:
 {{ .Values.env }}: |
   {{- with .Values.annotiations1 }}
     {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
   {{- end }}

Then use
helm upgrade --install install_name chart_name --set env=dev


but I need configurations from annotiations1 and annotiations2, for dev db and uat db, when I had two dev dbs was ok, because in annotiations I had one configuration but now I need to have two

@Mateusz your pod is connecting to 2 dbs at the same time?

yes my pod is connecting to 2 dbs at the same time
